# Typescript does not produce an output JS file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, bing-maps, bing

I downloaded the Bing Maps 7 Typescript library and am desparate to use it.  How do I do it?

I am using VS 2012 RC. I tried the TSC line command -- no output.

Any advice?

Comment: Will this make sense for you? http://www.irisclasson.com/2012/10/28/example-windows-store-app-winrt-adding-and-using-bing-map/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

The typescript compiler needs a typescript file to compile. If you create a typescript project from the vs 2012 template, you should have a working greeter app. Then start expanding it and build your app.

Comment: I do have the Bing Maps 7 Typescript files. They fail